# Convert yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss to dayoftheweek, dd of monthname yyyy

Tags: php, date

I almost have this by

```
$this->fecha = '2013 05-05 05:55:05'
$yearvalue = date("Y", strtotime($this->fecha) );
$monthname = date("F", strtotime($this->fecha) );
$dayvalue = date("d", strtotime($this->fecha) );
$printFecha = "$dayvalue of $monthname $yearvalue";
```

Which outputs 5 of May 2013

How can I get the name of the day of the week?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this,

```
echo date('l j \of F Y', $this->date);
```

Your output will be something like this

```
Sunday 5 of May 2013
```

Answer (score 1):

Using date of 2005-05-12:

```
echo date("l", mktime(0, 0, 0, 5, 12, 2005));
```

you'd get 'Thursday'.